# Potential race condition in action builder authentication using cookie

Tags: scala, authentication, cookies, playframework

I'm using play action builder to check whether a user is authenticated when a user visits a page via cookie mechanism.

Checking is done by verifying authentication token encrypted in the cookie matches the token stored in the db for the particular user.

If the user is authenticated, then i will regenerate a new token and then store the updated token inside database and update the result with cookie containing the updated token.

I can see a possible race condition(although it happens very rarely in my opinion) during the token regeneration process.

I believe the situation happens when requesting the page at the same time :

> Page1 -> authenticated -> token regeneration -----> save to db (replaced) -> cookie updated
>
> Page2 -> authenticated -> token regeneration -> save to db -------> cookie updated(replaced)

So now, the browser cookie containing the token will not match with the value in DB.

How can I improve this? Am i designing it wrongly ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to regenerate the token with every request? A user can easily double click a link and cause serious problems when handling tokens this way.

Comment: I did some research about the best practices to implement persistent cookie authentication(a.k.a remember me). From what i have observed, its safer if you can regenerate the token every request. Because if by chance, someone is able to steal the token. It is only valid until a user request for another page, comparing to re-generating it only during login/logout. I believe its a trade off of making your application safer but also more complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of altering the value of the authentication cookie so it is not reusable.

If the entire cookie is encrypted with out modifying the token itself. Using a timestamp in the cookie will change the unreadable cookies value. This will keep the cookie from being "replayed." Once the cookie is decrypted on the server side it can be checked against an acceptable sliding window.

You could also use the sliding window concept on the server side by storing older tokens for a small amount of time within the database. This would also allow you to do your constant token regeneration.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely took a look at it. Any useful links that I can take a look at?

Comment: I do not have a link based on this specific scheme. It just seems like the simplest adaptation to resolving race conditions. In reality I would recommend you use a plugin or a framework to manage authentication for you.